# Geometric explanation of a methodology in the article about Image Denoising

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, signal-processing, matrix-calculus, image-processing

In article [Ghimpeteanu G., et al. - A Decomposition Framework for Image Denoising Algorithms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7321034), I found as below:

> *Let $\displaystyle I : \Omega \subset R^2\mapsto R$ be a gray-level image, and $(x, y)$ be the standard coordinate system of $R^2$.We denote by $Ix
>  \hspace{.2cm}resp.Iy$ the derivative of $I$ with respect to $x
>  \hspace{.2cm}resp. y$, and by $\nabla I$ the gradient of $I$ . Our
>   image decomposition model for $I$ is a two-stages approach: first, we
>   construct an orthonormal moving frame $(Z_1, Z_2, N)$ of $(R3,\|
> \|_2)$ over $\Omega$ that encodes the local geometry of $I$ . Then, we
>   compute the components $(J^1, J^2, J^3)$ of the $R^3-$valued function
>   $(0, 0, I )$ in that moving frame. More precisely, we consider a
>   scaled version $\mu I$ of $I$ , for $\mu \in ]0, 1]$, and its graph,
>   which is the surface $S$ in $R^3$ parametrized by $\psi : (x, y)
> \mapsto (x, y,μ I (x, y))$*

**See snapshoot-**

[image: demo]

Please someone explain (possibly visualize **geometrically**) 4th and 5th line of the excerpt. i.e

---

> Our image decomposition model for $I$ is a two-stages approach: first, we construct an orthonormal moving frame $(Z_1, Z_2, N)$ of $(\mathbb{R}^3,\| \|_2)$ over $\Omega$ that encodes the local geometry of $I$ . Then, we compute the components $(J^1, J^2, J^3)$ of the $\mathbb{R}^3-$valued function $(0, 0, I )$ in that moving frame.

Comment: It's not very helpful to reference the line numbers. As far as I know, there's nothing that guarantees that the lines break in the same point in my screen and in yours (or is there?). I think you should repeat the sentences you need help with.

Comment: @fonini please see now i added all the details..

Comment: I was just helping you get some attention. And you got an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Each position in the image is assigned a local 3 dimensional ON coordinate system. The ON-system will vary with the localization ( which pixel we are at ). The transformation matrix to this three dimensional ON system is given by P matrix where you can see the $\nabla$ operators, corresponding to partial differentiation with respect to the spatial dimensions of the image. I also assume that subscript means partial differential wrt that dimension e.g. $I_x$ means partial differential of $I$ with respect to $x$ dimension. So the moving frame will be depending on the local partial differentials of the image ( treating it as a scalar function ).